# In memory SSL validation

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore, truststore

I do not want to do SSL validation using keystore/truststore on client side. The server gives me a cert(in the form of a String) and I want to validate this on the client side in memory. I think this is possible using java TrustManager API but do not know how to implement this. Explanation with examples would be of great help.

Comment: @Hamad Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: Too broad. See the JSSE Reference Guide.